# How to make a file read-only for other persons after being checked out by me in Subversion?

Tags: svn

I am new to Subversion. My colleague is able to checkout a file which I am already editing. This leads to conflict when he tries to commit the changes he has made to the file.

What I want is, if I do some changes to the file, the file should be read-only to other persons who are trying to edit it. So that they know that this particular file is being used by some other person.

How can I configure this on subversion? Is it has to be done on all the clients OR the configuration on server is enough?

Comment: Did you try [resolve](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.resolve.html)?

Comment: @devnull Instead, i want to make the file read-only for others when i check out. Thanks

Comment: You can [create locks](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.locking.html).

Comment: @devnull I actually read that while i was searching in google. But couldnt quite understand that, as i do not have basics in SVN. Could you please explain shortly on how to do this ? Thanks

Comment: How could a short explanation be more understandable than the long and detailed explanation with examples that is in the official documentation. What don't you understand?

Comment: I recommend you read the [Versioning Models](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.basic.version-control-basics.html#svn.basic.vsn-models) chapter. In general, using locks makes Subversion less useful so it should be avoided when possible.

Comment: @devnull do **not** provide links to outdated SVNBook. 1.5 is too outdated. Use 1.7 instead.

Comment: Merging *IS* more effective way - you'll never be show-stopper for team

Answer (score 4):

You can mark a file as needs-lock in the repository:

```
svn propset svn:needs-lock "*" myfile.doc
svn commit
```

Then the next time everyone updates the file will become read-only in their checkout. In order to edit they now need to lock it:

```
svn lock mfile.doc
```

which registers that you have the file locked in the repository: you'll see this as a `K` in svn status and they'll see an `O` to mean someone else has locked the file. Once you commit, or `svn unlock` it you'll release the lock.

As [Álvaro comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16355321/make-a-file-read-only-for-other-persons-after-being-check-out-by-me-in-svn-how#comment23432568_16355321), though, you should avoid setting up locking unless you really need it. Use it only for binary files that SVN cannot merge.